# drupal htaccess redirect to new domain with folders

Tags: .htaccess, drupal

I need to redirect a old domain with a foldery to a new domain with that same folder ie.

```
www.mysite.com/k12/connect to www.mynewsite.com/k12/connect
```

connect is dynamic, entered by the user.

Comment: What does "connect is dynamic" mean? Is this relevant for the redirection?

Comment: connect is a taxonomy term

Answer (score 0):

Since everything is the same on the old and new server, you can just use [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)

```
Redirect / http://www.mynewsite.com/
```

As soon as it works properly, you can use a permanent redirect

```
Redirect permanent / http://www.mynewsite.com/
```